# Google Sheet: formula to loop through a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

It's not hard to do this with custom function, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it using a formula. Because datas won't automatically update when using custom function.

So I have a course list sheet, each with a price. And I'm using google form to let users choose what courses they will take. Users are allowed to take multiple courses, so how many they will take is unknown.
Now in the response sheet, I have datas like

| Order ID | User ID | Courses | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 38 | courseA, courseC | What formula to put here? |
| 1002 | 44 | courseB, courseC, courseD | What formula to put here? |
| 1003 | 55 | courseE | What formula to put here? |

and the course sheet is like

| course | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 23 |
| B | 33 |
| C | 44 |
| D | 23 |
| E | 55 |

I want to output the total for each order and am looking at using `FILTER` to do this. Firstly I can get a range of unknown length for the chosen courses

```
=SPLIT(courses, ",") // having named the Courses column as "courses"
```

Now I need to filter this range against the course sheet? not quite sure how to do it or even if it is possible. Any hint is appreicated.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(IFERROR(
 VLOOKUP(SPLIT(C2:C, ", "), {F1&F2:F, G2:G}, 2, 0))*1, 
 ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(C2:C, ", "))))^0)))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zJUIAhEXZgTMPcuD7jB36zxSWUup0hTHPOe6SPJjqgM/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please take a look at my answer as well?

Comment: @shenkwen see the demo spreadsheet... I added step-by-step guide to the final formula

Answer (score 0):

As I need time to digest @player0's answer, I am doing this in a more intuitive way.
I create 2 sheets to store intermediate values.
The first one is named "chosen_courses"

| Order ID | User ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | =IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(index(courses,Row(),1),","))),"") |
| 1002 | =IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(index(courses,Row(),1),","))),"") |
| 1003 | =IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(index(courses,Row(),1),","))),"") |

In this sheet every row is a horizontal list of the chosen courses, and I created another sheet

| total | course price |
| --- | --- |
| =IF(isblank(order_id),"",SUM(B2:2)) | =IFERROR(VLOOKUP('chosen_courses'!B2,{course_Names,course_price},2,false),"") |
| =IF(isblank(order_id),"",SUM(C2:2)) | =IFERROR(VLOOKUP('chosen_courses'!B2,{course_Names,course_price},2,false),"") |
| =IF(isblank(order_id),"",SUM(D2:2)) | =IFERROR(VLOOKUP('chosen_courses'!B2,{course_Names,course_price},2,false),"") |

`course_Names`,`order_id` and `course_price` are named ranges.

This works well, at least for now.

But there is a problem:
I have 20 courses, so in the 2nd sheed, there are 21 columns. And I copy the formulas to 1000 rows because that is the maximum rows you can get to using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Now sometimes when I open the sheet, there will be a progress bar calculating formulas in this sheet, which could take around 2 mins, even though I have only like 5 testing orders in the sheet. I am afraid this will get worse when I have more datas or when it is open by old computers.
Is it because I use some resource consuming functions? Can it be improved?

Comment: you are right to be afraid. larger dataset = longer calculation time. to combat this you should go for efficiency and use ArrayFormula instead of per-cell formula on each row which will halt your spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks. I am still learning to use ArrayFormula. I named a lot of column based ranges in my spreadsheet. It seems these named ranges not working very well with ArrayFormula. One of the things that confuse me is when used as a function's parameter, most of the time the named ranges behave like a value but sometimes (for example, when in a `FILTER` function) they behave like a range. And arrayFormula is another factor that affects named ranges' behavior. It gets more complicated when `arrayFormula` and `Filter` and other functions are used together, thus I often get range mismtach error.